# aggregate dictionary items into summary results

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like

```
    mydict={
        (a,1):0,
        (a,2):0,
        (a,3):0,
        (a,4):1,
        (a,5):2,
        (a,6):2,
        (a,7)=0,
        (a,8)=0,           
}
```

I want to summarize it in to

```
mysummarydict={
    (a,1,3):0,
    (a,4,4):1,
    (a,5,6):2,
    (a,7,8):0
    }
```

These values are from a dataset about intervals that do not overlap but that can have gaps. The first dictionary now has one entry for each single point and I would like to get a second dictionary that has a summary of those adjacent points that share a common value. Can you guide me to the best solution for this in python 2.6?
Thanks

Comment: These are not Python dictionaries; they are not even valid expressions in Python.

Comment: What about the `(a,2)=0` line?

Comment: This doesn't look like python. What's a? What happened to 2? What are the keys and values of the dictionary?

Comment: Can you provide a deeper example, how might this vary? Will the keys be grouped so nicely?  Will there be gaps?

Comment: Valid Python: `a = {'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, '5':1}`

Comment: yes sorry for being too quick about the first pass. I updated the question so the example now looks like a real python dictionary.

Comment: @biomed: It's still not valid Python.

Comment: @biomed. You still messed it up. No commas. The point of posting code that compiles is that it makes it convenient for people that want to answer your question to download it, play with it, and give you a good answer.

Comment: @biomed: You should explain your problem properly and the output should be consistent if you expect to get good help.

Comment: (a,2) will get aggregated in to the new interval in the new dictionary because it is in the middle of 1 and 3.

Comment: Is a dictionary really the best data structure for this? They're inherently unordered, and what you want to do is operate on key value pairs in order.

Comment: I am open to other solutions that use a data structure other than dictionaries it was simply a matter of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mydict={
        ('a', 1): 0,
        ('a', 2): 0,
        ('a', 3): 0,
        ('a', 4): 1,
        ('a', 5): 2,
        ('a', 6): 2,
        ('a', 7): 0,
        ('a', 8): 0,           
}

data = mydict.items()
data.sort()

def groupkey(item):
    return item[0][0], item[1]

result = {}
for v, group in groupby(data, key=groupkey):
    char, value = v
    nums = [item[0][1] for item in group]
    result[char, min(nums), max(nums)] = value

print result
```

The result:

```
{
 ('a', 1, 3): 0
 ('a', 4, 4): 1, 
 ('a', 5, 6): 2, 
 ('a', 7, 8): 0, 
}
```

Comment: `for (char, value), group in ...` -- maybe better?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great but I guess I wasn't clear enough in my question in the first pass. I updated the question to better represent the need. Your answer outputs one interval for each original value but I need something a little different as depicted in the question now.

Comment: @biomed: change `return item[0][0], item[1], item[0][1]` to `return item[0][1]`.

Comment: I applied return item[0][1] and it seems to generate the correct format but the output seems to be lacking some data points. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you store this data in a list instead, it becomes much easier:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]

def interval(v):
    head = tail = next(v)
    for tail in v:
        pass

    return head[0] + 1, tail[0] + 1

print({interval(v): k for k, v in groupby(enumerate(mylist), key=itemgetter(1))})
```

giving

```
{(5, 6): 2, (1, 3): 0, (7, 8): 0, (4, 4): 1}
```

Comment: In case it isn't clear, `interval` returns the first and last position values in the iterable (with a fencepost correction).

Answer (score 0):

I found a shorter and faster method:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from time import clock

mydict={('a', 1): 0,
        ('a', 2): 0,
        ('a', 3): 0,
        ('a', 4): 1,
        ('a', 5): 2,
        ('a', 6): 2,
        ('a', 7): 0,
        ('a', 8): 0,
        }

A,B,C = [],[],[]

for i in xrange(1000):

    t0 = clock()
    data = mydict.items()
    data.sort()
    def groupkey(item):
        return item[0][0], item[1]
    result1 = {}
    for v, group in groupby(data, key=groupkey):
        char, value = v
        nums = [item[0][1] for item in group]
        result1[char, min(nums), max(nums)] = value
    A.append(clock()-t0)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------

    t0 = clock()
    data = [ [a,b,c] for ((a,b),c) in mydict.items()]
    data.sort()
    result2 = {}
    for (char,value),group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0,2)):
        nums = [item[1] for item in group]
        result2[char,nums[0],nums[-1]] = value
    B.append(clock()-t0)

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    t0 = clock()
    data = [ [a,b,c] for ((a,b),c) in mydict.items()]
    data.sort()
    result3 = {}
    for ((char,value),nums) in [ (cle,[item[1] for item in group]) for cle,group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0,2))]:
        result3[char,nums[0],nums[-1]] = value
    C.append(clock()-t0)

print 'result1==',result1
print 'result2==',result2
print 'result3==',result3
print 'result1==result2==result3==',result1==result2==result3
print id(result1)==id(result2),id(result2)==id(result3),id(result3)==id(result1)


print '{:.1%}.'.format(min(B)/min(A))
print '{:.1%}.'.format(min(C)/min(A))
```

a result:

result1== {('a', 5, 6): 2, ('a', 4, 4): 1, ('a', 7, 8): 0, ('a', 1, 3): 0}

result2== {('a', 5, 6): 2, ('a', 4, 4): 1, ('a', 7, 8): 0, ('a', 1, 3): 0}

result3== {('a', 5, 6): 2, ('a', 4, 4): 1, ('a', 7, 8): 0, ('a', 1, 3): 0}

result1==result2==result3== True

False False False

87.0%.

93.2%.